# How to avoid stdscr overlapping in ncurses?

Tags: c++, ncurses, curses

In my application I have two *WINDOW* objects, which bisects the terminal window, like a split-screen. But when I'm using *wprintw()* 
I can't see any output on the screen. I'm sure, that *stdscr* overlaps these two windows. How can I avoid this overlapping?
Maybe I need to use *wrefresh()* or *refresh()*? I've tried, but it doesn't help.
Here is the simplified part of my code. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

```
WINDOW *win1 = newwin(10, width, 0, 0);
WINDOW *win2 = newwin(10, width, width, 0);

wprintw(win1, "First window: ");
wprintw(win2, "Second window: ");

wrefresh(win1);
wrefresh(win2);

while((ch = getch()) != KEY_F(2)) {}

endwin();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stdscr` by definition covers the screen, so it will always overlap with any other window you create. The solution is to avoid using `stdscr` if you want to have multiple windows.

But the place where you're referencing `stdscr` is perhaps not obvious -- it's in the call to `getch()`, which can also be read as `wgetch(stdscr)`. This does an implicit `wrefresh(stdscr)`. which overwrites the screen with the (blank) contents of `stdscr`.

You can avoid this problem by changing the `getch()` call to `wgetch(win1)` or `wgetch(win2)`. In this example, it doesn't matter which window you choose; if you were displaying the input, you'd want to use the window where the input should appear.

Alternatively, you could call `refresh()` right at the start of the program, before refreshing `win1` or `win2`. Then, as long as you never wrote anything to `stdscr`, you could safely use `getch()` as much as you liked, since the implicit `refresh()` would find nothing updated in the window to display.

Comment: Suppose I have 2 windows, one in the left top corner and the second one in another area. How wgetch(win2) will detect that key is pressed? Only if cursor will be in the same area?

Comment: There is really only one input queue. Passing a specific window pointer to wgetch() tells curses where the *output* should appear, as well as, to use the window-specific input settings of that window (keypad, timeout, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

Sorry guys for wasting your time! I found an answer by myself!
Here is the code:

```
WINDOW *win1, *win2;
int maxx, maxy, halfx;

getmaxyx(stdscr, maxy, maxx);
halfx = maxx >> 1;

win1 = newwin(maxy, halfx, 0, 0);
wgetch(win1, "First window");
wrefresh(win1);

win2 = newwin(maxy, halfx, 0, halfx);
wgetch(win2, "Second window");
wrefresh(win2);
```

Comment: This doesn't do the same things as the code in your original question (there's not even any input), so it's not clear how this is a solution to the problem.

Comment: Of course there is no input, because I didn't include it here. But it solves my problem very well - there is no overlapping of stdscr. Maybe I need to explain the solution more clearly. Thanks to [you](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2906189/william-mcbrine), for explaining that _getch()_ function use the _stdscr_ by default.